# SQL query for returning the latest record for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure.

```
LocId    Value1    Value1Date                
.............................................
1        50        2012-10-20 14:21:00.000      
1        70        2012-10-21 14:21:00.000      
1        90        2012-10-22 14:21:00.000      
1        100       2012-10-23 14:21:00.000    
2        20        2012-10-20 14:21:00.000       
2        40        2012-10-21 11:21:00.000      
2        70        2012-10-22 14:21:00.000     
2        80        2012-10-23 14:21:00.000 
3        50        2012-10-20 14:21:00.000       
3        70        2012-10-21 11:21:00.000      
3        80        2012-10-22 14:21:00.000      
3        90        2012-10-23 14:21:00.000
```

What I want to achieve is that, for each [LocId], I need the [Value1] of the latest datetime (i.e. 2012-10-23). The returned table should look like:

```
LocId    Value1    Value1Date                
.............................................
1        100       2012-10-23 14:21:00.000
2        80        2012-10-23 14:21:00.000
3        90        2012-10-23 14:21:00.000
```

Can anyone give a hand please? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use rank over partition like so:

```
select * from
(select locid, value1, value1date, 
  rank() over (partition by locid order by value1date desc) as rank
  from table1) t
where t.rank=1
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c697/11)

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using `Common Table Expression` and a `Window Function`

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  LocID, VAlue1, Value1Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LocID ORDER BY Value1Date DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  LocID, VAlue1, Value1Date
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5eb2a/1)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This approach will work.

```
select locid, value1, value1date
from yourtable join
(select locid id, max(value1date) maxdate
from yourtable
group by locid) temp on id = locid 
and value1date = maxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the mysql query that does what you're looking for.  I don't really know about other SQLs.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LocID = n ORDER BY Value1Date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you're querying from a program, you can use:

```
SELECT LocID FROM table ORDER BY LocID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

to get the total number of IDs (assuming they're consecutive), and then put it in a loop to get all of the most recent dates.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your suggestion about getting all the id's and looping through them is very inefficient.  It's not to often that I down vote something, but, I just don't like this answer.

Comment: Quoted from stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down:

When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Instead of voting down:

If the post is spammy or offensive, flag it.
If the question is duplicate or off-topic, flag it for moderator attention.
If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.