# Returning the single latest record for every device id in the table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have the following table data:

```
    +-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------+-----------------+
    | id  | date_timer_off      | date_timer_on       | event_done | device | user | admin_email     |
    +-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------+-----------------+
    | 145 | 2017-03-08 16:54:00 | 2017-03-08 16:55:00 | T          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 146 | 2017-03-08 16:54:00 | 2017-03-08 16:55:00 | T          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 147 | 2017-03-08 16:54:00 | 2017-03-08 16:55:00 | T          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 148 | 2017-03-08 16:55:00 | 2017-03-08 16:56:00 | T          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 149 | 2017-03-08 16:55:00 | 2017-03-08 16:56:00 | T          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 150 | 2017-03-08 16:55:00 | 2017-03-08 16:56:00 | T          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 151 | 2017-03-08 18:28:00 | 2017-03-08 18:29:00 | T          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 152 | 2017-03-08 18:28:00 | 2017-03-08 18:29:00 | T          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 153 | 2017-03-08 18:28:00 | 2017-03-08 18:29:00 | T          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 154 | 2017-03-08 18:32:00 | 2017-03-08 18:33:00 | F          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 155 | 2017-03-08 18:32:00 | 2017-03-08 18:33:00 | F          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 156 | 2017-03-08 18:32:00 | 2017-03-08 18:33:00 | F          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 157 | 2017-03-08 18:58:00 | 2017-03-08 18:58:00 | F          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 158 | 2017-03-08 18:58:00 | 2017-03-08 18:58:00 | F          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 159 | 2017-03-08 18:58:00 | 2017-03-08 18:58:00 | F          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 160 | 2017-03-08 19:02:00 | 2017-03-08 19:03:00 | F          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 161 | 2017-03-08 19:02:00 | 2017-03-08 19:03:00 | F          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 162 | 2017-03-08 19:02:00 | 2017-03-08 19:03:00 | F          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    +-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------+-----------------+
```

The result I am in need of is as following:

```
    +-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------+-----------------+
    | id  | date_timer_off      | date_timer_on       | event_done | device | user | admin_email     |
    +-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------+-----------------+
    | 160 | 2017-03-08 19:02:00 | 2017-03-08 19:03:00 | F          |      3 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 161 | 2017-03-08 19:02:00 | 2017-03-08 19:03:00 | F          |      4 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    | 162 | 2017-03-08 19:02:00 | 2017-03-08 19:03:00 | F          |      5 |    4 | admin@admin.com |
    +-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------+-----------------+
```

It needs to return only the ONE latest record per device id in the table and only if the event_done status is 'F' or in other words false.

The records must also be in the current minute that the request is being made, as the database will be queried every 20 seconds to update a list of timers.

For example if the request is made at 19:02:20 then there should be a check to check whether the date_timer_off or date_timer_on fields falls within the minute the request is made (19:02:20), thus returning the above result set.

I tried implementing the answer from this post, [SQL query for returning the latest record for each ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399962/sql-query-for-returning-the-latest-record-for-each-id), but was unsuccessful.

This is the current query im using in production environment but it's causing problems such as next events not firing when they should.

```
    select * from timers_data data where data.date_timer_off >= :today AND data.date_timer_off <= :tomorrow AND data.date_timer_on >= :today AND data.date_timer_on <= :tomorrow AND data.event_done = 'F' ORDER BY data.id DESC
```

I also tried this:

```
    select * from timers_data where event_done = 'F' and (date_timer_off >= now() or date_timer_on >= now()) ORDER BY id desc;
```

It works when running it on MySQL, but there seems to be a problem when I run it in my Spring application using Spring's JPA CrudRepository as below:

```
    @Query(value = "select * from timers_data where event_done = 'f' and (date_timer_off >= now() or date_timer_on >= now()) ORDER BY id desc;", nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<TimersData> findTimersForToday();
```

This is what I currently use in my project:

```
    @Query(value = "select * from timers_data data where data.date_timer_off >= :today AND data.date_timer_off <= :tomorrow AND data.date_timer_on >= :today AND data.date_timer_on <= :tomorrow AND data.event_done = 'F' ORDER BY data.id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<TimersData> findTimersForToday(@Param("today") Date today, @Param("tomorrow") Date tomorrow);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The records must also be in the current minute that the request is being made" and if there is no such record no records are returned?  Why isn't this a simple `WHERE sysdate() between date_timer_off      and  date_timer_on and event_Done = 'F'`?  it assumes you can't have devices with timers that overlap on time but based on the question that seems reasonable.

Comment: After reading what you've tried... change your OR to and  and your >= to <= on the first datetime_off...`select * from timers_data where event_done = 'F' and (date_timer_off <= now() AND date_timer_on >= now()) ORDER BY id desc;`

Comment: Thank you @xQbert, will also try that if the solution has problems along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a subselect with in clause based on tuple  that  match the device and the max(date..)

```
select  * from  timers_data data 
where (device, date_timer_off) in ( 
     select device, max(date_timer_off)
     from timers_data data 
     where data.date_timer_off >= :today 
     AND data.date_timer_off <= :tomorrow 
     AND data.date_timer_on >= :today 
     AND data.date_timer_on <= :tomorrow 
     AND data.event_done = 'F' 
    group by device ) 
ORDER BY data.id
```

Comment: It Works! So far. Thanks for the prompt response.